Cv axles and ball joints replacement is it the brakes, ball joint, axle nut but what else im at a stand still?
2004 Subaru impreza outback rs sport axle and ball joint replacement what else needs to be loosened to get axle and bj out?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
